# Integral Substitution $\text{csc }\theta \cot\theta$

Tags: integration, substitution

I have come across a question when researching integral substitution and I have no idea how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't understand what to do.

$$\int \text{csc}^2 2\theta \cot2\theta \,d\theta $$

I need to do the integral in two ways by using two different substitutions: $u = \cot 2\theta$ and $u = \text{csc } 2\theta$

Comment: Why not write it out in terms of sine and cosine?

Comment: @MarkBennet I don't know how to..

Comment: @ShaunaGoodmanFitzpatrick: come on, don't you know what $\text{cosec}$ and $\cot$ are ???

Answer (score 0):

With the substitutions you insisted, here are the following solutions:

**Solution 1:** Let $u=\cot 2\theta$. Then $du=-2\csc^2 2\theta d\theta$.
Thus,$$\begin{align}
\int \text{csc}^2 2\theta \cot2\theta \,d\theta&=-\frac{1}{2}\int udu\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{u^2}{2}+k\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\cot^2 2\theta}{2}+k
\end{align}$$

**Solution 2:** Let $u=\csc 2\theta$. Then $du=-2\csc 2\theta \cot 2\theta d\theta$. Thus,
$$\begin{align}
\int \text{csc}^2 2\theta \cot2\theta \,d\theta&=\int \big[\csc 2\theta\cdot\csc 2\theta\cot 2\theta d\theta\big]\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int udu\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{u^2}{2}+C\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\csc^22\theta}{2}+C\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: I need to use the two substitutions given though

Comment: Can you please explain where you got x = 2θ?

Comment: On second thoughts I discarded my answer, as the question explicitly asks for these changes of variable.

Comment: Do you know of any good sources I could learn this about? I don't understand where most of these lines are coming from

Comment: @Shauna Goodman Fitzpatrick Just goggle about trigonometric integrals and you will a lot of examples.